Under extrusion problem
I think I have a big under-extrusion problem with my Ender 3. When I start printing, the first two or three layers print perfectly, but the nozzle gets clogged at some point and the extruder starts skipping.
When I pull the filament out of the extruder I notice that it has expanded inside the nozzle, I've tried lowering the printing speed, retraction distance, and even turning off retraction.
When I turn off retraction, the quality is terrible, but at least it prints completely.


Printer: Ender 3
Print temp: 190 °C
Bed temp: 50 °C
Filament: Creality PLA
Infill: 20%
Speed: 50 mm/s
Layer height: .2 mm
Retraction: 4 mm @ 25 mm/s


This looks like an e-step issue. This YouTube video has good info on calibrating it, and coincidentally uses an Ender 3 to do so. He also has another video that discusses calculating the retraction speed and distance - I believe it's in one of his Cura videos about things you should always check, but I don't remember exactly which one.

Thank you so much, I'll give it a try to both videos
